# AutoMapper With Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, automapper

Is there any AutoMapper package for a flutter (like in c#)?

**Example:**

we are mapping the Entity to EntityModel.

mapper = Mapper();

Entity = Entity();

EntityModel = mapper(Entity );

Comment: This website map json to dart model: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party, but after a long time using all kinds of mapping packages, which were buggy, had a limited set of features, and were mostly months/years unmaintained and without any response, etc., we created the AutoMappr package that might suit your needs. It does not use reflection/mirrors but rather code generation, so the code is faster, and you can easily debug it.

Try it out and let us know on GitHub or Discord what you think. 
It already has many built-in features, and more can be added on top of it.

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_mappr

Comment: @kapiltk, what do you mean? It clearly does. https://pub.dev/packages/auto_mappr

Comment: Its my mistake.  Am looking an auto mapper for android, and IOS.

Answer (score 1):

This package might fit your needs, [smartstruct](https://pub.dev/packages/smartstruct)
, if you look at the example they provide:

```dart
class Dog {
    final String breed;
    final int age;
    final String name;
    Dog(this.breed, this.age, this.name);
}
```

```dart
class DogModel {
    final String breed;
    final int age;
    final String name;
    DogModel(this.breed, this.age, this.name);
}
```

```dart
// dogmapper.dart
part 'dogmapper.mapper.g.dart';

@Mapper()
abstract class DogMapper {
    Dog fromModel(DogModel model);
}
```

Then any custom mappings or explicit maps you can add attributes:

```dart
@Mapper()
class DogMapper {
    @Mapping(source: 'dogName', target: 'name')
    Dog fromModel(DogModel model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so, there is nothing like C# mapper in dart, but you can check this [lib](https://pub.dev/packages/automap).

let me know if this is what you want.